# Convert voronoi edges into polygons

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, voronoi

Currently I am trying to get Voronoi polygons dividing a plane of a certain size (e.g. 1000x1000 with 500 random points).

For this purpose, I used Delaunay's triangulation - Bowyer Watson's algorithm. Thanks to this, I am able to generate points and properly connect the edges included in the Voronoi diagram. Unfortunately, in my case, I need a list of polygons (of which each polygon contains a list of its edges).

I tried to create a naive algorithm that would take the edges one by one and look for the next ones to create a final polygon and so on - unfortunately without success. I was also thinking about taking the vertices of the triangles and creating a circle until the polygon is formed (from the existing edges), but I am not sure if this is a good solution?

Is there any way to do it? Or should I use a different algorithm to get the Voronoi polygon list?
I have not found a suitable solution to this problem on the Internet, if there is one, I will be grateful for the link

Comment: So, you already have the edges (line segments) you just need to derive the polygons as edge-paths?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Yes i already have list of edges and i need to transform this into polygon list

Comment: I'd suggest building a Doubly Connect Edge List (DCEL) using the algorithm described [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2516).

Answer (score 1):

- Select E an arbitrary edge
- Add vertices in E to polygon
- Select point P slightly to one side of E
- If point inside plane

  - Select one vertex of selected edge
  - Select E2 new edge from vertex with smallest angle on side with point P
  - Add second vertex in E2 to polygon
  - Repeat last two steps until reach other vertex in E
  - Add polygon to solution, if not already included
- Repeat with point on other side of edge
- Repeat until all edges processed

[image]

Comment: I have a problem with "Select E2 closest new edge from vertex to P" which if the nearest edge is "wrong" I mean what if we have two edges from point P, one is correct (leads to a right polygon) and the other leads us in the wrong direction. In some cases, I can go through the entire plane and create one giant polygon or even stuck. How to determine which edge is correct?

Comment: If there are several edges, then select the one that is closest to P.

Comment: A better test would be the smallest angle between E and E2

Comment: It might work, I'll give it a try and come back with the results :)